# Control over "Allow push notification" alert

Tags: iphone, ios5, push-notification, ios6

When I register my app for push notification I get an alert on launch asking permission for registering my app for push notification. My questions are (for iOS5 & iOS 6 if u know):

1. What control I have over that alert?
2. Can I control that alert, not show it, and make user to allow/not allow push-notifications later in the app using a checkbox/button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not control push notification alertView.

What you can do is to check the allowed push types:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes]`

in to the app and inform the user to go to settings and enable push notification for your app.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! If possible, could you provide a reference link to docs related to this, I am unable to find so.. :(

Comment: can I control when to show that alert, maybe by registering later for PN on press of a button and not at the startup.. ??